# Display how long it has been since something doubled

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, data-science

I read an interesting stat that since last year, the stock market has gone up 100% (i.e., doubled) in the shortest time on rest -- and I am looking to test/replicate this claim.

The data below is from FRED (Federal Reserve data depository) and it's for the WILL5000 index, which goes back to 1970, as the S&P only goes to 2011.

```
| DATE                |   WILL5000 |    50%   |
| 1970-12-31 00:00:00 |       1    |    0.5   |
| 1971-01-01 00:00:00 |     nan    |    nan   |
| 1971-01-04 00:00:00 |     nan    |    nan   |
| 1971-01-05 00:00:00 |     nan    |    nan   |
| 1971-01-06 00:00:00 |     nan    |    nan   |
|         ...         |     ...    |    ...   |
| 2021-07-21 00:00:00 |   216.54   |  108.27  |
| 2021-07-22 00:00:00 |   216.68   |  108.34  |
| 2021-07-23 00:00:00 |   218.84   |  109.42  |
| 2021-07-26 00:00:00 |   219.32   |  109.66  |
| 2021-07-27 00:00:00 |   218.07   |  109.035 |
```

One way I thought was to add a column with half the value of the WILL5000 index and then using code to search for a value below this level (which would be 100% move), and recording how many days it has been since.

I cannot seem to find how to do this anywhere - and would love to hear of any other ways to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has `O(n2)` steps for `n` points in your series.

For the `ith` point in your sequence, you'll need to check if `wj >= 2wi` for all `j > i`. Stop at the first `j` (if any) that satisfies your requirements in each case. In other words, hold one date fixed as a baseline and then look for the doubling condition across all future dates; do this for all possible baseline dates.

In Pandas, this means you'll have to (i) cross-merge the dataframe with itself and filter it to the "upper triangular" (i.e., `j > i`) portion, (ii) find the first time to double for each group on `i`.

Here's Python+Pandas code that will get the job done:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# load your data --> construct synthetic df for this example
np.random.seed(52)
date_axis = pd.date_range('1970-01-01', '2021-01-01', freq='M')
n = len(date_axis)
raw_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': date_axis, 'ticker_value': 300.0 * np.random.rand(n)})

# create n^2 df
df = pd.merge(raw_df, raw_df, how='cross').sort_values(by=['date_x', 'date_y'])

# restrict to upper triangle
df = df.loc[df.date_y > df.date_x, :]

# add a column to check if doubling condition is met
df['is_at_least_double'] = (df.ticker_value_y >= 2.0 * df.ticker_value_x)

# throw away values that don't meet the condition
df = df.loc[df.is_at_least_double, :].drop(columns=['is_at_least_double'])

# pick up the first value that satisfies the condition -- this is why we did the sort
df = df.groupby('date_x').first().reset_index()

# find intervals
df['interval'] = df.date_y - df.date_x

# find the smallest interval; tie-breaker is the one with the earliest base date
df.sort_values(by=['interval', 'date_x'], inplace=True)
solution = df.iloc[0]

print(solution)
```

The comments explain the steps in the code. I recommend running it line-by-line in the console and inspecting the intermediate results to understand what's going on.